# Getting name from sender(Multi Type) on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to have a event for all label,images,textblock,.... on wpf?

```
Label a=new Label();
a.name="object"+counter;
counter++;
a.MouseDown += _MouseDown;
grid.Children.Add(a);

Image b=new Image();
b.name="object"+counter;
counter++;
b.MouseDown += _MouseDown;
grid.Children.Add(b);
```

And event could be something like this:
Instead of (Object) we are using one type (Image) or (Label)

```
void _MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     var scrollViewer = (Object)sender;  
      **and here I could get name of it**
}
```

So let me to know if it's possible to have all of them on one event please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it to a superclass that *has* the `Name` property. Actually, casting an `object` to `Object` is useless, they are the same thing and `Object` does not have a `Name` property.

```
 var scrollViewer = (FrameworkElement)sender;
```

By simply looking up the MSDN documentation for [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) you find:

> Name
>   Gets or sets the identifying name of the element. The name provides a reference so that code-behind, such as event handler code, can refer to a markup element after it is constructed during processing by a XAML processor.(**Inherited from FrameworkElement**.)

(Bold mine)

Comment: It's right and thanks, how about "Rectangle or ScrollViewer", I must to provide another event for these ?

Comment: `Rectangle` and `ScrollViewer` also inherit from `Frameworkelement`, as you can easily see on MSDN.